# How to close an already opened programmatically popup window in android?

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow, onitemclicklistener

I seted an OnItemClickListener in my ListView which open a pop up window.
However, when I click on another item on my list - another pop window is opened and I don't know how to get the already opened window so I can close it.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Here's my code that opens the pop up window:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);


                Object checkExistence = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                int imgID = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(checkExistence.toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ","_"), "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.img1);

                imageView.setImageResource(imgID);

                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                        popupView,
                        Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }});

                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(list, 300, -1250);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Add a class member that references to popup window being shown. E.g. Popupwindow pw. first dismiss it is already showing, then assign the new reference to pw, pw = new PopupWindow() and then show it on click item

Comment: Thank you!! :) It's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

and alternatively

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the comments, you can use a variable with a larger scope to retain a reference to the popup window. Then you can close it with `dismiss()`.

```
// class member variable
PopupWindow popupWindow;

// ...

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // ...

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // dismiss the popup window
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }});

        // ...

    }
});
```